# CamelContext defined in Beans.xml . How do i instantiate the camelContext route programatically

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, applicationcontext

I have a camel context defined in the springs beans.xml.

Now i want to programatically invoke the route in camel context. How do i Do that. I want to programatically do this because I want one of my multiple nodes to run this download. I dont want all the nodes with this camel to run the download. I am planning to run this as a job or use zookeeper but dont want to change the way we have written the camel route.

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
   <!-- Camel context which holds the route definitions -->
   <camelContext id="camelpriceroutebean" errorHandlerRef="errorHandler"
              xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="download-from-ftp" autoStartup="true" startupOrder="1">
```

Now i have tried using following code

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/springbean.xml"); 
    CamelContext camel = (CamelContext) context.getBean("camelpriceroutebean"); 

    List<Route> routes = camel.getRoutes();
```

But the springbean.xml is throwing expcetion . Is there another way to handle this. ?

Answer (score 0):

See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html and this http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html. You need to startup Spring/Camel and keep the JVM running and allow the route to run and download from the FTP server. This happens automatic, you do not *call the route* to make it run when its consuming from a FTP endpoint.

I suggest to study Camel some more how it works etc to better understand it. There is for example a FTP example and others at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Comment: Hi Claus, I want to programmatically do it because i want to control the timing of downloads and one of my multiple machines only do this downloads. So  i am looking to invoke the route in my camel context